# Get column names if column contains matching value (without VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given a named range <kbd>Table1</kbd>, how do I return all names from the array <kbd>Table1[#Headers]</kbd> where a matching input value exist in that column?

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |

For the above sample data, I would like to return

| search_value | headers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b |
| 2 | b,c (or b,c,c) |
| 3 | c |

With the above sample data, I can count the occurrences of a named `search_value` with the formula `=SUM(--(Table1=search_value))`. Given the existing True/False array from that formula, I've been trying to get relative cell mapping information. Sadly

- [`XMATCH`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211224054947/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) only evaluates on a 1-dimensional array
- [`AGGREGATE`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211227055145/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) is promising but I've so far been unable to evaluate [`CELL("address",{})`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211224054847/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) (or similar) such that it *returns* an array that I can use with `AGGREGATE`

The workbook in question is a shared workbook hosted in OneDrive so I'd like to avoid VBA if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (with Office 365) would be:

```
=FILTER(Table1[#Headers],BYCOL(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1,E2,0)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x))))
```

where E2 is search value.
[image]

### concatenated

Sorry - I just realized that you want a concatenated output:

```
=TEXTJOIN( ",", 1, FILTER(Table1[#Headers],BYCOL(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1,E2,0)),LAMBDA(x,MAX(x)))) )
```

[image]

### Another approach based on Excel for Web

This depends on SEQUENCE which is supported in Excel for Web. Hopefully, it works on Sharepoint. If not, then there is a (cumbersome) way to tease out sequences using ROW(), but it would be easier if you don't have to go there.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,
     UNIQUE(IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[#Headers],
                    LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH(Table1,E2,0)*COLUMN(Table1[#Headers]),-1),
                          SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table1),COLUMNS(Table1),-1))),
                    ""),
            1) )
```

Comment: I think you just saved me an hour of rubber-ducking with [`MAKEARRAY`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210727103412/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/makearray-function-b80da5ad-b338-4149-a523-5b221da09097). TY!

Comment: Sure @PeterVandivier  - I have just picked up LAMBDA helpers and, honestly, don't think I know MAKEARRAY well enough to pull that off either. BYCOL, BYROW and SCAN are becoming my hammer. ;-)

Comment: Worth noting that the Excel web viewer (for SharePoint & OneDrive hosted docs) doesn't seem to support this at this time. But I imagine that's what you were communicating with the Office 365 comment.

Comment: @PeterVandivier - actually, I didn't know that. In this case, there is a non-LAMBDA approach, but I have to think about it.

Comment: @PeterVandivier - i am not sure if SP can support SEQUENCE, but it is supported for Excel for Web and that gives me hope. In any case, I added an another approach. I hope it works. I guess, this is what I meant by "BYCOL being my hammer". Once I know it exists, then the brain will take the path of least effort.

Comment: Can I suggest you post the `SEQUENCE` solution as a second answer? Firstly because it seems to have an off-by-one error as written. Secondly because I think my comment about the web viewer was inaccurate/incomplete. Looks like for whatever reason I got opted into some beta corporate licensing situation with my O365 download and those formulas weren't available on the machines of other folks on my same team.

Comment: Ah, no, not strictly an off-by-one. I was just starting my `Table1` in B2 instead of A1 so `COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])` is offsetting based on that. Using `(COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])-CELL("col",Table1)+1)` yields a more complete answer. It also contains the duplicate values (which is worth mentioning as an alt behaviour)

Comment: Hi @PeterVandivier - I see your point on duplicate answers. I did not think of it or test it. A good cure for that would be UNIQUE. I will put that in the answer above. I did not quite follow the point on the off-by-one, but I think you're saying it's OK now.